# RegEx - 1 to 10 Alphanumeric Spaces Okay

Tags: regex, spaces, alphanumeric, variable-length

New to Regular Expressions. Thanks in advance!

Need to validate field is 1-10 mixed-case alphanumeric and spaces are allowed. First character must be alphanumeric, not space.

**Good Examples:**

"Larry King"

"L    King1"

"1larryking"

"L"

**Bad Example:**

" LarryKing"

This is what I have and it does work as long as the data is exactly 10 characters. The problem is that it does not allow less than 10 characters.

[0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z ][0-9a-zA-Z ][0-9a-zA-Z ][0-9a-zA-Z ][0-9a-zA-Z ][0-9a-zA-Z ][0-9a-zA-Z ][0-9a-zA-Z ][0-9a-zA-Z ]

I've read and tried many different things but am just not getting it.

Thank you,

Justin

Comment: The last character can it be a space?

Comment: [0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z ]{0,9}

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what environment you are using and what engine. So I assume PCRE (typically for PHP)

this small regex does exact what you want: `^(?i)(?!\s)[a-z\d ]{1,10}$`

**What's going on?!**

- the `^` marks the start of the string (delete it, if the expression must not match the whole string)
- the `(?i)` tells the engine to be case insensitive, so there's no need to write all letter lower and upper case in the expression later
- the `(?!\s)` ensures the following char won't be a *white* space (`\s`) (it's a so called negative lookahead)
- the `[a-z\d ]{1,10}` matches any letter (`a-z`), any digit (`\d`) and spaces () in a row with min 1 and max 10 occurances (`{1,10}`)
- the `$` at the end marks the end of the string (delete it, if the expression must not match the whole string)

Here's also a small visualization for better understanding.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/bT5YyqH8plUnmbb9)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `[0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z ]{0,9}`

The `{x,y}` syntax means between `x` and `y` times inclusive. `{x,}` means at least `x` times.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this.

```
[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9 ]{0,9}
```

This first part ensures that it is alphanumeric.  The second part gets your alphanumeric with a space. the {0,9} allows from anywhere from 0 to 9 occurrences of the second part.  This will give your 1-10

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `^[(^\s)a-zA-Z0-9][a-z0-9A-Z ]*`

Not a space and alphanumeric for the first character, and then zero or more alphanumeric characters.  It won't cap at 10 characters but it will work for any set of 1-10 characters.

Comment: `[(^\s)a-zA-Z0-9]` means "a character class that contains: parenthesis, caret, ascii letters (uppercase and lowercase) and ascii digits"

Answer (score 0):

The below is probably most semantically correct:

```
(?=^[0-9a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9a-zA-Z]$)^[0-9a-zA-Z ]{1,10}$
```

It asserts that the first and last characters are alphanumeric and that the entire string is 1 to 10 characters in length (including spaces).

Answer (score 0):

i think the simplest way is to go with `\w[\s\w]{0,9}`

Note that `\w` is for `[A-Za-z0-9_]` so replace it by `[A-Za-z0-9]` if you don't want `_` 
Note that `\s` is for any white char so replace it by  if you don't want the others

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the space is not allowed at the end too.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9 ]{0,8}[a-zA-Z0-9])?$
```

or with posix character classes:

```
^[[:alnum:]](?:[[:alnum:] ]{0,8}[[:alnum:]])?$
```